# Fastest way to delete millions of registers in sql server

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, database-performance

I have a big table in SQL server which contains 136.651.894 of rows. One month ago were inserted 7.668.309 new rows with an error in one field. In the moment of the insert I create a copy table to ensure that this does not happen, but nobody saw the error and I dropped the table one week after the load process.

To delete the rows I create a procedure which select the max values per myID from the original table (this is because the error was that we add more zeros in the field value, so the max value is wrong and this register has to be deleted), and in a backup table I search this registers for myID and value and I delete the row.

For example one row is:

<kbd>ID</kbd> 
<kbd>myId</kbd>  <kbd>Value</kbd>  <kbd>Other fields...</kbd> 
 <kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>2345</kbd>  <kbd>25948238400</kbd> <kbd>Other values...</kbd>

The procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_DELETE_ROWS] 
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @myId VARCHAR(22)
    DECLARE @value VARCHAR(20)

  DECLARE c_max CURSOR 
  FOR
    SELECT myId,max ([value]) as maxValue
    FROM t1Original
    group by  myId
    order by maxValuedesc

  OPEN c_max
    FETCH NEXT FROM c_max
    INTO @myId ,@value

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        print 'Deleting '+@myId+' y caudal '+@value +''
        DELETE FROM [t1OriginalCopy] WHERE myId=@myIdAND value=@value
        FETCH NEXT FROM c_max 
        INTO @myId,@value
    END

  CLOSE c_maxs
  DEALLOCATE c_max
END
```

The problem of this is that it takes too much time, now is over 1 day of execution...

How can I improve the performance of this process?

Comment: can you create a simple subset of the data in both tables to highlight the issue and show what you want the result to be?

Comment: use transactions: begin trans; delete from...; commit;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `CURSOR`.

Try this

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Dense_rank()OVER(partition BY myId ORDER BY value DESC) rn,*
         FROM   [t1OriginalCopy])
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```

If the table(`t1OriginalCopy`) will be used in parallel in some other operation then you may have to split the delete into batches to avoid locks

Comment: hi can you explain for me why using dense_rank() is better then cursor loop ? I have a cursor that delete in batches should I replace it with rank() over ?

Answer (score 0):

The server might be overloaded and unable to do other tasks if you try to delete all at once, so do it in batches that you can stop and continue later if necessary. Adjust 'top(100)' to change batch size, depending on how the server manages.

`Declare @rcount int=1
    Select MyID, max([Value]) as maxvalue into #temp from t1Origina group by myID
    while @rcount>0
        begin
        Delete top (100) o
        FROM t1Origina o
        inner join #temp t
        on o.myId = t.myId and o.value = t.maxvalue
        set @rcount=@@rowcount
        END
    Drop #temp`

Comment: I am trying your statement and it does not work because says that is a syntax error near inner. I don't find the error. Furthermore I do not understand how I will only delete the registers that I need, because If I have for example 1005 registers that are wrong I have to throw this 10 times,  and in the 11th time it will delete 5 that are wrong but 95 that now are maximum because the incorrect maximum has been deleted before. Now that maximums are correct.

Comment: Sorry, I've adjusted the typo. A temp table holds the list of registers to delete and the loop checks against that list 100 at a time until there are no more.